# Intro to Stokey / Lucas and Sargent / Ljungqvist

Tags: macroeconomics, recursive-macroeconomics

I would like to ask, if you can recommend me some introduction to these 2 macro textbooks: Stokey / Lucas and Sargent / Ljungqvist, which I will be using in the 2nd year MA in Economics.

So something at a lower level (maybe intuitive explanation of the math), but which will help me to progress to these 2 textbooks.

Thank you!

Comment: If Stokey Lucas and Prescott is a future benchmark, then all the intermediate economics books will not get you very far. Instead, you should read some texts on real analysis, metric spaces, topology, and functional analysis. I would therefore recommend reading something like 'Foundations of Mathematical Economics' by Carter.

Comment: EB3112, thanks for recommendation!

Comment: A long long time ago, when I was still a student, I found the following a quite useful intro to dynamic models: [Ferguson and Lim: "introduction to dynamic economic models"](https://www.amazon.com/Introduction-Dynamic-Economic-Models-Ferguson/dp/0719049962)

Comment: If you know some calculus I think that Ljungquist/Sargent is pretty much self contained at least in the 3rd edition - the first five chapters and chapter 7 are an introduction to the methodology. The usual dynamuc macro course starts only with chapter 8.